# MimeKit: 'RSACng' is currently not supported

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2, mimekit

I'm trying to create `S/MIME` email with `MimeKit` in the .NET Core App. It's working fine with local certificate like this:

```
var signer = new CmsSigner("cert.pfx", "password");
message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, message.Body);
```

To make app more secure, I've uploaded my certificate to the Azure KeyVault. And here's my problems has begun.

The idea is to use only certificate from Azure KeyVault without any passwords etc (so only store reference to the KeyVault instead of storing two links (KeyVault cert + KeyVault certPass)).

Here's how I'm trying to get certificate from the Azure KeyVault.

```
private static async Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificate()
{
    var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var azureKeyVaultCert = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://<myapp>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secretName>/<secretId>");

    var certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(azureKeyVaultCert.Value);
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
    return cert;
}
```

And then:

```
var cert = new GetCertificate();
var signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
```

Here I got error like this: `MimeKit: 'RSACng' is currently not supported.`

After that I tried another approach. It's working fine, however, I need to use my password. I don't think this is good idea (despite the fact I can also use Azure KeyVault for cert password).

```
private static async Task<byte[]> GetCertificateBytes()
{
    var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var azureKeyVaultCert = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://<myapp>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secretName>/<secretId>");

    var certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(azureKeyVaultCert.Value);
    var certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    certCollection.Import(certBytes, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    return certCollection.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password");
}

var certBytes = await GetCertificateBytes();
using(var certStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(certBytes))
{
    var signer = new CmsSigner(certStream, "password");
}
```

In case when I use `await keyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync()`, I got an error that there's no private key.

Also, there's difference between certificates created via `new X509Certificate2()` and `X509Certificate2Collection.Export()`.

Maybe I miss something?

Comment: This commit in MimeKit might fix your issue: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/commit/a29d5414549f6db9d77f556d06aa502f4b84a970 - can you grab v2.4.1.8 from https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MimeKit and test it?

Comment: @jstedfast - I will try a bit later. With this package I can't even start solution. =)

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @jstedfast I tried the Nuget with netcoreapp3.1 and still get the RSACng is not supported exception.  Am I reading the git commit right in that the change is focused on "NET46 || NET47 || NET48 || __MOBILE__" and not dotnet core?

Comment: There’s no build for netcoreapp3.1, there is only net4x and netstandard2.0. You need to test the fix using a net46+ target.

Comment: Wouldn't netcoreapp3.1 be able to use netstandard2.0?

Comment: When I updated ASP.Net Core to 3.1 I had to move from the full framework being behind it (which presumably means I pulled the .NET Standard version of MimeKit and not the net46+ version).  I guess my question is, in the change above is there a reason that can't use .NET Standard (the directive seems to be excluding netstandard)?.  E.g. does the RSACng not exist in .NET Standard?